# É possível voltar a likebox antiga do Facebook?

Tags: facebook, api

É possível voltar a likebox antiga do Facebook?

Eu preciso voltar pois preciso aumentar o número de 'friends faces'. Caso não seja possível, pode me dizer se é possível aumentar esse número na nova lightbox?

Answer (score 1):

Receio que isto não seja possível, pois a antiga [**Like Box**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages) foi completamente desabilitada com o lançamento do [Graph API v2.3 e substituída pelo Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3_changes).

O **Page Plugin** basicamente é uma nova versão aprimorada do Like Box e com um nome diferente.

> Podes acessar [**este link**](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/like-box-plugin-now-2-4x-faster/10151322164543920) para ver o que mudou com esta nova versão do
>   Page Plugin

Antigamente para aumentar o número de caras de pessoas a ser apresentado, bastava apenas aumentar a altura do Like Box que automaticamente o número da quantidade de caras seria aumentado consoante a sua altura. Infelizmente (pelo menos por agora) esta solução não se aplica a esta nova versão.

Contudo, podes sempre fazer essa sugestão no grupo [Facebook Developer Community](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers).

Comment: Muito bem descrito +1

Answer (score 0):

Pois é, isso mudou. Para exibir o rosto caso 2 ou mais amigos tenham curtido a página você pode setar o atributo "data-show-faces" para true, na tag html do Facebook.

Exe.:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Já aquele box que a gente estava acostumado pelo que vi agora só existe caso o link seja de uma fanpage, ou seja, para curtir a fanpage. Para isso usa-se o Page Plugin.

Exe.:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Esse também possui outras opções de configuração. Dá uma olhada lá em https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin .